# make a textbox visible on a tr(row) click and print the same of the data on button click in a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

my expectation is: Say i have two rows, The textbox will be hidden and the label will be available as a display when a user click on a selected row the label should be hidden and the text box should be visible of that particular row and after that if the user clicks on the button then the data or the clicked row textbox value should be printed #showresult

current: am getting the color on a row clicked but am not sure how to make a text box visible on a particular row and print the same in a div on button click

JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr').click(function () {
        if(this.style.background == "" || this.style.background =="white") {
            $(this).css('background', 'red');
        }
        else {
            $(this).css('background', 'white');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" width="100%" id="table1">
    <tr>
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
        <th>Column3</th>
        <th>Column4</th>
        <th>Column5</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><label>data1</label> <input type="text" value="1" /></td>
        <td><label>data2</label>  <input type="text" value="2"  /></td>
        <td><label>data3</label>  <input type="text" value="3" /></td>
        <td><label>data4</label>  <input type="text" value="4" /></td>
        <td><label>data5</label>  <input type="text" value="5" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>data6</label> <input type="text" value="6" /></td>
        <td><label>data7</label>  <input type="text" value="7" /></td>
        <td><label>data8</label>  <input type="text" value="8"  /></td>
        <td><label>data9</label>  <input type="text" value="9" /></td>
        <td><label>data10</label>  <input type="text" value="10" /></td>
    </tr>

</table>

<input type="button" value="printdata"/>
<div id="showresult"></div>
```

Comment: Hint: use `display: none` to hide and `$(elem).show()` to show

Comment: @l19 thanks for the reply but how can i print the data

Comment: Add an event handler to the button that updates the div

Comment: @l19 am not sure how to do this a small help will be thankful if u post the same in a answer am new to this

Comment: what value exactly do you want to show?

Comment: @wallek876 , the text box which was visible after the row clicked

Comment: @l19 u can join me hear if u dont mind http://jsfiddle.net/eK8X5/7010/#&togetherjs=EVNGAF0DGN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with you explanation i think this example match what you are trying to accomplish.

css:

```
.selected {
    background: red;
}
```

Html:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" width="100%" id="table1">
    <tr>
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
        <th>Column3</th>
        <th>Column4</th>
        <th>Column5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>data1</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data2</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data3</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data4</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data5</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>data6</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data7</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data8</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data9</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data10</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input id="printdata" type="button" value="printdata" />
<div class="showresult">1: <span></span></div>
<div class="showresult">2: <span></span></div>
<div class="showresult">3: <span></span></div>
<div class="showresult">4: <span></span></div>
<div class="showresult">5: <span></span></div>
```

js:

```
$('tr input').hide();

$('tr').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($( e.target ).is("input")) {
        return;
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        $('input', this).toggle();
    } else {
        $('tr.selected input').hide();
        $('tr.selected').toggleClass('selected');
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        $('input', this).toggle();
    }
});

$('#printdata').click(function () {
    $('.showresult').each(function (index) {
        $('span', this).html('');
        $('span', this).html($('tr.selected input').eq(index).val());
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wallek876/vmj5h2a8/)

```js
$('tr input').hide();

$('tr').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($( e.target ).is("input")) {
        return;
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        $('input', this).toggle();
    } else {
        $('tr.selected input').hide();
        $('tr.selected').toggleClass('selected');
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        $('input', this).toggle();
    }
});

$('#printdata').click(function () {
    $('.showresult').each(function (index) {
        $('span', this).html('');
        $('span', this).html($('tr.selected input').eq(index).val());
    });
});
```

```css
.selected {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" width="100%" id="table1">
    <tr>
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
        <th>Column3</th>
        <th>Column4</th>
        <th>Column5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>data1</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data2</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data3</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data4</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data5</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>data6</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data7</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data8</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data9</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>data10</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input id="printdata" type="button" value="printdata" />
<div class="showresult">1: <span></span></div>
<div class="showresult">2: <span></span></div>
<div class="showresult">3: <span></span></div>
<div class="showresult">4: <span></span></div>
<div class="showresult">5: <span></span></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your support i was expecting the same and appreciate for your support but how can i hide the label on toggle at a time either label or text box should be visible

Comment: absolutely i think i am stressing u alot but i need one more help??

Comment: can the print button be disabled if any of the textbox aren't visible or if they are visible and the textbox do not have the value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87088/discussion-between-pauli-and-wallek876).

Comment: if there are multiple tables the this effects for them all CAN'T IT BE FOR PARTICULAR

Comment: @Pauli sure just target the table you want like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wallek876/vmj5h2a8/7/

Answer (score 0):

Could be helpful

[a working example on codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwdYMZ)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr').click(function () {
        if(!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
            $('tr').removeClass('active')
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});

$("#b-print").click(function(){
  $('div#showresult').html('');
  $.each($('tr'), function(idx, obj){
    $.each($(obj).find('input[type=text]'), function(idx2, obj2){
      $('div#showresult').append($(obj2).val()+", ");
    });
    $('div#showresult').append('<br/>');
  });
});
```

```css
tr input[type=text]{
  display: none;
}
tr.active{
  background: red;
}
tr.active input[type=text]{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" width="100%" id="table1">
    <tr>
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th>Column2</th>
    <th>Column3</th>
    <th>Column4</th>
    <th>Column5</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><label>data1</label> <input type="text" value="1" /></td>
    <td><label>data2</label>  <input type="text" value="2"  /></td>
    <td><label>data3</label>  <input type="text" value="3" /></td>
    <td><label>data4</label>  <input type="text" value="4" /></td>
    <td><label>data5</label>  <input type="text" value="5" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label>data6</label> <input type="text" value="6" /></td>
    <td><label>data7</label>  <input type="text" value="7" /></td>
    <td><label>data8</label>  <input type="text" value="8"  /></td>
    <td><label>data9</label>  <input type="text" value="9" /></td>
    <td><label>data10</label>  <input type="text" value="10" /></td>
</tr>

</table>

<input type="button" value="printdata" id="b-print"/>
<div id="showresult"></div>
```

Comment: But all the data  re printed which are not edited also

Comment: yes you are correct and  on button click , the same data should be printed

Comment: try to change data, then click on "printdata" to see the result

Comment: @ Odai Alali ma b am not shore how to change it can u plz help me on that??

Comment: by changing textbox values after clicking on a row.. run the code snippet and play with it